# Install win2003 server hp oem cd on Virtualbox

Tags: windows, virtualization, virtualbox

I want to install a windows 2003 server OEM HP on my virtualbox, but it gives-me this error

> This system is not a supported platform.

HP has a solution to this problem to VMWare but not Virtualbox. 
http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=110&prodSeriesId=420496&prodTypeId=18964&objectID=c00970200

Basically we have to put this
`SMBIOS.reflectHost=TRUE`on the vmx file.

Can i do something similar to this on Virtualbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently need to prime your virtual machine with the correct DMI / SMBIOS information. See [the appropriate section in the virtualbox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changedmi) on how to do this. You would need to previously extract the DMI data from your host, either by using WMI queries (if you are on Windows) or by running dmidecode (if your host is Linux).

Comment: Many thanks. Really helpful link. I will try and then let you know if it works.